# Codeigniter Active Record, Multiple where conditions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Here is my table structure. and I want to get records between provided date range.

```
|--------------|---------------------|
|      id      |   year   |  month   |
|--------------|---------------------|
|      1       |    2015  |  01      |
|      2       |    2015  |  02      |
|      3       |    2016  |  02      |
|--------------|---------------------|
```

I tried with following query, but didn't work.

```
return $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('tourist T')
                ->where('T.year >=', $where['s_year'])
                ->where('T.month >=', $where['s_month'])
                ->where('T.year <=', $where['e_year'])                            
                ->where('T.month <=', $where['e_month'])
                ->get()->result();
```

Comment: What's the output you're getting?

Comment: Use `$this->db->last_query()` to print your query and check what your query return

Comment: query output SELECT `T`.`id`
FROM (`tourist` T)
WHERE `T`.`year` >= 2015
AND `T`.`month` >= 1
AND `T`.`year` <= 2016
AND `T`.`month` <= 3

Comment: Check month in 03 01 format

Comment: add single quote and month with 0 prefix

Comment: here my query is trying to get the record whose year >= 2015 AND month >= 1 AND year <= 2016 AND month <= 3. searching for record which meets every condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
   $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('test T')
            ->where('T.year >='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month >='.$where['s_month'])
            ->where('T.year <='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month <='.$where['s_month'])
            ->get()->result();
```

Comment: This is the query output SELECT `T`.*
FROM (`tourist` T)
AND `T`.`year` >=2015 and T.month >=1
AND `T`.`year` <=2016 and T.month <=3, but only works when you remove the month parameter from second where clause.

Comment: you need to use bracket:
SELECT T.* FROM (tourist T) where (T.year >=2015 and T.month >=1) AND (T.year <=2016 and T.month <=3 )

Comment: thank you for reply, what if I want to add other where clause like  $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('test T')->where(T.country_id, '13')  
            ->where('T.year >='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month >='.$where['s_month'])
            ->where('T.year <='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month <='.$where['s_month'])
            ->get()->result();

Comment: you need to do like this:
$this->db->select('*') ->from('test T') ->where('T.country_id =13 and T.year >='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month >='.$where['s_month']) ->where('T.country_id =13 and T.year <='.$where['s_year'].' and T.month <='.$where['s_month']) ->get()->result();

Comment: Thank you, saved my day.